What's the purpose of the holes on the Cabri G2 fenestron blades?
What is the purpose of the holes on the blades of the Cabri G2 fenestron? In my opinion drilling the blades like that weakens their cross section under the action of the centrifugal force. Is it something related with the manufacturing process or with the blades aerodynamics and boundary layer?


I think that the holes you are mentioning are placed on the hub and they are bigger because the straps are located bellow the blades roots. The holes through each of the blade are very small and I'm not sure what you can inspect from them.

It's the aviation equivalent of whistle tips Woo Wooo!

@MichaelHall The text in the article is misleading. As I suspected the holes for straps inspection are on the hub - check link and link . The reason for the small holes drilled through every blade still stays unknown.

I stand corrected, thanks.

Are the holes only present for fenestron blades?

If changing the angle of attack moves plastic skin relatively to steel core and if a gap is created, holes could be for air pressure equalization.

The Cabri G2 has "fail-safe injected plastic blades" (pdf) on the tail rotor. Those holes might simply be the injection points.

@sophit They do not look like gating points, but I think mins has a credible idea: If those blades are hollow and the hub is solid, those holes are for pressure equalisation. Two for redundancy, and the size need not be larger than they are.

@PeterKämpf: I can count at least seven of them on each blade

@sophit OK, did not check that picture. But that makes a gating point even less likely, as only one is needed (and best for avoiding junctions). But then, more than two equalisation holes would also not be needed.

These holes come from the manufacturing process. They inject plastic into the blade mould through these holes. The holes don't serve any aerodynamic purpose. That's the explanation I got at a recent visit to the plant in Aix-en-Provence.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
